# How to solve congruence using diophantine equation?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations

Id like to know how to solve this congruence,
`2x + 5y ≡ 0(mod 7)`so far i've tried solving it like a Diophantine equation which gave me `2x + 5y - 7z = 0 and x = (-5/2)y + (7/2)z` and got stuck on this step.

Comment: Since the inverse of $2\pmod 7$ is $4$ just multiply your congruence by $4$ and rearrange.

Comment: could you  explain this please?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Just try what I said.  What do you get if you multiply by $4$?  Be sure to reduce the coefficients $\pmod 7$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy to solve in $$2x+5y=7z$$ as, $$x=y=z$$ is a solution trivially.  Adding 5 to x, and subtracting 2 from y, also adds 0. Adding or subtracting 0 is idempotent. Adding or subtracting any solutions ( for x and y at least) gives a new solution, for this same reason (we are adding or subtracting 0 mod 7).We Also have adding 6 to x and subtracting 1 from y adds 7.etc  So, out to absolute value 10 we have:

- 21 with $x=y=z$
- 14 with $x-5=y+2=z$
- 14 with $x+5=y-2=z$
- etc. 
  (0,0,0) being one of the most trivial 21